# Add property to entity framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in my dataaccess layer, i also use this as my object model.

psudo object model:

```
public class Item{
    public string ID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Xml Data{get;set;}
}
```

The Data property is the key here. i would like to be able to do this:

Psudo:

```
var item = Items.Get(id: 1);
var xmlValue = item["key"];
```

I would like to be able to extend the EF generated class Item with a new property where i use some logic to get a value by key from the xml.

My problem is:

1. I find EF data model not very easy to work with and when i want to update the Item table, i cannot be sure my extended logic will stand.
2. I dont think i want to add an extracted model and do a convert the EF Item to My.Item every time. This will be a heavy opeartion if the table gets big.

What is a good way to extend the EF object model?

that i dont

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use a partial class and define the extra fields / properties.

Converting from EF Item to your item is trivial if the fields are the same, you could just use  [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

i'm leaning towards the partial class solution though.

Comment: You could also use extension methods.